# Server Not Responding Using Put method with Spring web client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

So I am trying to upload a file to my server using the put method. I am encountering what I believe to be some strange behavior using the Spring web client, the following is my code.

```
//setup properties
String publishUrl = "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api";
File schemaFile = new File("myFile.xml");
String catalogName = "myFileName";
String jndiName = "myJNDI";
boolean overwrite = true;
boolean enableXmla = true;

//setup form
MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
form.add("uploadAnalysis", new FileSystemResource(schemaFile));
form.add("catalogName", catalogName);
form.add("Datasource", jndiName);
form.add("overwrite", overwrite ? "true" : "false");
form.add("xmlaEnabledFlag", enableXmla ? "true" : "false");
form.add("parameters", "Datasource=" + jndiName);

//Set up credentials
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Admin", "password"));

//set up http client
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

//create client request factory using httpcient
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory fact = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);

//create rest template
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(fact);

//create http headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

//use put method. 
  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(form, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.exchange(publishUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
```

**This works, my file gets uploaded to the server.** However, I never get a response from the server, I always get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api":localhost:8080 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:431)
```

I had previously used Jersey and would always get a response, but for this project I am required to use Spring. I was curious if there are any headers or other properties I would have to set to get a response? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your server?

Comment: what exactly do you want to see?

Comment: What does it do? It's possible it crashes after getting the file and never sends a response.